# what is the difference in rendering row elements of React table directly using render and rendering via cell property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-table

I want to know what is the difference between rendering rows of Column1 and Column2 in the below code.

```js
<ReactTable
  data={this.state.data}
  columns={[
    {
      Header: "Column1",
      accessor: "Column1",
      render: props => {(...Some touchable prop with onChange Event)}
    },
    {
      Header: "Coulmn2",
      accessor: "Column2",
      minWidth: 145,
      Cell: row => (
        <TableSwitch row={row} onChange={this.handleActiveChange} />
      )
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: I don't see a prop named render for columns in the react-table docs

Comment: yes, the prop named render is not there for Column , but then also it works fine and hence i want to know which one is best for usage.

Comment: I tried it in React-table demo, and render doesn't seem to work for me. can you create a reproducible demo

Comment: u can see in renderers section of react table that it is mentione as "JSX or any rendered react component".

Comment: All I can see is that even though the render function is called, its return value is not used to render anything, its just the accessor that is rendering the value, whereas in case of Cell, the cell is rendered according to the returned property

Comment: yeah , true i too noticed it now.